# How to migrate from CodeIgniter database to Laravel database

Tags: database, codeigniter, model, laravel, migration

I have decided to migrate from my CodeIgniter app to laravel specially for their rails-likely handling of the database.

The problem though is that i have 800mb of database to migrate. How can I do this in a good and fast way? The tutorials i have seen is based on old laravel models to new ones. Which makes me confused.

I also use codeigniter's crypt library for the user passwords. How can I migrate this?

Comment: I have the same problem. If I success to migrate password data, I will post the solution here. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases are pretty much the same in Laravel or Codeigniter, if your tables are good the way they are for you and they have a primary key named `id` (this also is not mandatory) you can just connect with Laravel in your database and it will work just fine.

For your new  tables, you can create new migrations and Laravel will not complaint about this.

Well, but if you really need to migrate to a whole new database, you can do the following:

1) rename the tables you need to migrate

```
php artisan migrate:make
```

2) create all your migrations with your  and migrate them:

```
php artisan migrate
```

3) use your database server sql utility to copy data from one table to another, it will be way faster than creating everything in Laravel, believe me. Most databases will let you do things like:

```
INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM users_old
```

And in some you'll be able to do the same using two different databases and columns names

```
INSERT INTO NEWdatabasename.users (firstName+' '+Lastname, email)
SELECT name, email
FROM OLDdatabasename.
```

Or you can just export data to a CSV file and then create a method in your Laravel seeding class to load that data into your database, with a lot of data to import, you just have to remember to execute:

```
DB::disableQueryLog();
```

So your PHP doesn't run out of memory.

See? There are a lot of options, probably many more, so pick one and if you need help, shoot more questions.

Comment: I have a question - i got aware of laravel+voyager and it seems to be a good choice to have as pre-built boilerplate project so i can build my projects - with an existing admin panel. Question: is voyager a good fit to use for custom programming - like in codeigniter. What bothers me is the BREAD functionality - i don't think one has to implement all of your controller/models with these generators?! All in all - is laravel a good choice for converting my codeigniter project so that i have pre built admin area with access control and login etc. @antonio-carlos-ribeiro